# using select lists in html to call different javascript functions

Tags: javascript, listbox, selection

I an trying to write a hta that lets a user

- Select an office
- Select a floor (linked to the office)
- when selecting the level, run a function specific to that "floor"

I have no idea if i am on the right track, but at present i have the two selection lists looking right,

Here is what i have so far

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var varieties=[
["Floor..."],
["Floor...","Level 6","Level 7"],
["Floor...","77 Level 12","77 Level 13","77 Level 14","77 Level 15"],
["Level 9"]
];

function LevelBox(idx) {
var f=document.myform;
f.levelbox.options.length=null;
for(var i=0; i<varieties[idx].length; i++) {
    f.levelbox.options[i]=new Option(varieties[idx][i], i); 
    }    
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="LevelBox(0);">
<form name="myform" method="post" action="http://www.mysite.com/mysite">
<fieldset>
<select name="sitebox" onchange="LevelBox(this.selectedIndex)">
    <option value="SiteSelect">Site ...</option>
    <option value="Site1">Site1</option>
    <option value="Site2">Site2</option>
    <option value="Site3">Site3</option>
</select>
<select name="levelbox">

</select>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

but now i need to execute a function based on what is chosen in "FloorBox"

So when selecting the floor the respective functions are executed

`Level 6 - function changeContent6`

`Level 7 - function changeContent7`

`Level 12 - function changeContent77_12`

`Level 13 - function changeContent77_13`

And so on.

Any guidance on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
$('select[name="levelbox"]').change(function(){
 var level = $(this).val();
 var level_index = level.split(' ');
 level_index[1]; // use it to call content function
});
```

Comment: thanks, sorry but im really new to this,  I tried pasting that in to the script section  right after the Levelbox form but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: you have to use level_index[1] as variable and call function with concatination to content like content+level_index[1]();